# Node.js and HTML5 Audio

Tags: node.js, html5-audio

I'm trying to get my node.js server to server up audio files for the HTML5 audio tag. Currently I'm referencing audio files via an express staticProvider, but this will allow the sound to play once and then never again.

From what I've been able to gather in order for the sound to work properly with seeking or looping I need to provide the "Content-Range" header when my audio file is requested. I highly doubt that the express staticProvider is doing this for me, so it would seem that I need to serve the file up using custom code. Unfortunately I'm fairly new to node.js and things like serving files are still a little beyond me. Can anyone offer some advice on how I can provide the appropriate metadata for my audio files?

*[EDIT] (Removed old server code since it won't do anyone any good!)*

Sorry, I don't typically ask questions this broad, but I'm really at a loss as to where to start with this one. Any suggestions?

**[SOLUTION]**

So it appears that the solution is just to use updated software. I was trying express rather than the built-in connect HTTP middleware because I thought connect wasn't doing static file  serving right. Turns out, I was just looking at the documentation for a newer version of connect while the version that comes with node is a bit older. Once I updated my connect library (I just used npm to install the latest, for those that are curious), the following worked beautifully:

```
var connect = require('connect');
var server = connect.createServer(
    // If your server errors on this line, saying it doesn't know what 
    // "static" is you need to get the latest connect!
    connect.static(__dirname + '/public')
);
server.listen(PORT);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The static serving logic is done by the underlying connect server (using its static middleware). There is code for 'Content-Range' headers (see [here](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/static.js), about line 148), but these headers are only set when the underlying client (in your case, the browser's HTML5 implementation) sends the correct request headers.

Maybe [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/8339e0dc825c057f/822b2dd48f36e890) from google groups can help you out. The topic is slightly different (video streaming), but i think the core of the problem is about the same.

Comment: I've been reading that post and piecing together what I can based off of it. It's been slow progress, though. Thanks for pointing me at the static middleware, though! I hadn't even thought to look there, which seems rather stupid in retrospect.

Comment: Aha! And therein lies the solution! The connect middleware included with node.js is old, and doesn't have the Content-Range code you pointed out. By installing a newer version of connect I was able to get it working! Thank you!

Comment: Thats the curse/blessing of developing in a fast-paced environment like node.js ;) glad i pointed you to the right direction!